# Testing array length with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to implement unit test for a Spring boot project.

I'm new with unit testing in Java and I learned that I can test my project in the service layer. So I have this:

```
    @Mock
    private ICampusRepository campusRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CampusServiceImplementation campusService;

    private List<Campus> campusList = new ArrayList<>();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        campusList.add(new Campus(1, "Campus Name 1", "ACTIVE"));
        campusList.add(new Campus(2, "Campus Name 2", "ACTIVE"));
        campusList.add(new Campus(3, "Campus Name 3", "INACTIVE"));
    }
```

Then, for testing I have some very basic test:

```
    @Test
    void getAllCampus() {
        when(campusRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(campusList);
        assertNotNull(campusService.getAllCampus());
    }
```

I want to make a test to verify if certain method returns a list of campus with "ACTIVE" attribute only, I'm trying to do this:

```
    @Test
    void listAllActiveCampus() {
        when(campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus()).thenReturn(campusList);
        assertEquals(2, campusService.listAllActiveCampus().size());
    }
```

But the test result is:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :0
```

The question is: Should I create a new array with 2 values only? Is there a better way to create better conclusive test?

**EDIT**

campusService code:

```
    @Override
    public List<Campus> getAllCampus() {
        return campusRepository.findAll();
    }

...

    @Override
    public List<Campus> listAllActiveCampus() {
        return campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus();
    }
```

The repository:

```
public interface ICampusRepository extends JpaRepository<Campus, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM catSede WHERE sedeEstatusId = 3", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Campus> findAllActiveCampus();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Full test Class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class CampusServiceImplementationTest {

    @Mock
    private ICampusRepository campusRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private CampusServiceImplementation campusService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    void getAllCampus() {
        List<Campus> campusList = new ArrayList<>();
        campusList.add(new Campus(1, "Campus Name 1", "ACTIVE"));
        campusList.add(new Campus(2, "Campus Name 2", "ACTIVE"));
        campusList.add(new Campus(3, "Campus Name 3", "INACTIVE"));
        when(campusRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(campusList);

        List<Campus> result = campusRepository.findAll();
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(3, result.size());
        verify(campusRepository, times(1)).findAll();
    }

    @Test
    void listAllActiveCampus() {
        List<Campus> campusList = new ArrayList<>();
        campusList.add(new Campus(1, "Campus Name 1", "ACTIVE"));
        campusList.add(new Campus(2, "Campus Name 2", "ACTIVE"));
        campusList.add(new Campus(3, "Campus Name 3", "INACTIVE"));

        when(campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus()).thenReturn(campusList);

        List<Campus> result = campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus();
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(2, result.size());
        verify(campusRepository, times(1)).findAllActiveCampus();
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CampusServiceImplementation implements ICampusService {

    private final ICampusRepository campusRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Campus> getAllCampus() {
        return campusRepository.findAll();
    }


    @Override
    public List<Campus> listAllActiveCampus() {
        return campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface ICampusRepository extends JpaRepository<Campus, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM catSede WHERE sedeEstatusId = 3", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Campus> findAllActiveCampus();
}
```

Comment: show us the codes of the `campusService` please

Comment: I just added the code to the question

Comment: Do you happen to have any Mockito related annotations on your test class?

Comment: @Lesiak Only Mock and InjectMocks

Comment: Can you please post the full code for your test class, service class and repository class ( including class level annotations.) in order to reproduce the error ?

Comment: when(campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus()).thenReturn(campusList);
This statement is the issue, you are returning the entire list in your mock. better return a filtered list which will contain only active records. then your test will pass.

Answer (score 0):

There is something off: When you write

```java
when(campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus()).thenReturn(campusList);
assertEquals(2, campusService.listAllActiveCampus().size());
```

and your `setUp()` is as shown, then you should get the Error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :3
```

because you configured your ´campusRepository´ so that when called with ´findAllActiveCampus()´ it should return ´campusList´ which in turn contains **3** not **2** elements , even if only **2** elements are "ACTIVE".

Remember that the `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM catSede WHERE sedeEstatusId = 3", nativeQuery = true)` is not executed at all in this test, because the repository is just a mock!

Comment: So is there a way to test that my query works without touching the database?

Comment: While correct, your answer is a bit misleading. This is another problem, potentially unrelated to why the ` campusRepository.findAllActiveCampus()` returns an empty list (and not a list of length 3).